# fortran 90 allocatable array already allocated on calling type bound procedure

Tags: pointers, runtime-error, fortran90, user-defined-types

I am getting this weird runtype error in my fortran code . I have a pointer to a user defined type A as an element of user defined type B. When I call a procedure associated with type A from a procedure in type B, I get allocated array already allocated runtime error. Has anybody seen this error?

Sorry Can't show the code. but here is roughly what is happening.

```
type B
   type(A),pointer :: obj
 contains
    procedure :: do_something
 end type B
type A 
    integer,allocatable:: long_array(:) 
  contains
    procedure :: do_something_to_long_array
end type A

 program main
  type(B) :: obj1
  type(A) ,target :: obj2

  allocate(obj2%long_array(10))
  obj1%obj=>obj2
  call obj1%obj%do_something_to_long_array()
 end program main
```

The call to do_something_to_long_array gives me that error. the procedure is implemented in my code and works when called directly on the object. I am able to access the values inside the long_array also. But I am unable to call the subroutine.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that error.  It usually happens when you try to allocate an array which is already allocated.  What I haven't seen is any of your code which would help SO to help you.

Comment: Problem solved. This was related to the version of the intel compiler I was using. On moving to a newer version the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've settled things, but just for the heck of it, the allocatable array in "type A" is iffy.  Having allocatable arrays in type definitions was not possible in many versions of FORTRAN90 until recently.  And the "already allocated" error is what it would return when it crashed.  I think this is probably why your newer compiler worked while the old one didn't.

Comment: I did not know that. I was mostly programming in Python till recently. Fortran 90 and on seem to allow programming in a very python like style with speed benefits. It seems kind of pointless not to allow allocatable arrays inside types as so many numerical problems need them.